# Why does my dog act scared of me when my fiancé is in the room but act loving towards me when we are alone?

Tags: dogs

So my fiancés ex roommates dog used to be all loving towards him when the ex roommate wasn’t around but the second the ex roommate was around the dog would start shaking like they were afraid of my fiancé well E B just tried to pull that stunt just now my so my fiancé came in the room to get something and she started acting like she was afraid of me when I tried to move move her or tell her no (she was trying to get in the way of my fiancé getting the item they needed) she even started doing the whole shaking theatric crap and barking like she was afraid yet like the literal second my fiancé left the room E B quit shaking and laid right at my feet can someone explain this bs to me  ‍♀️ ‍♀️(we got her from a local rescue she’s supposed to be a brindle Plott Hound-Beagle mix her previous owner had to go to a nursing home and their family didn’t want to take care of E B so they put her back in the rescue she was adopted from) no I don’t know the history of E B but she acts like she may have some trauma but I really can’t say for sure E B is 7 years old and has ran away 2 times but we fixed where she was escaping from and she pulls on the leash and when told no she won’t listen to either my fiancé or myself or she throws a literal tantrum and since we got her she’s relieved herself in the house even tho she goes outside lately she has taken to holding it in and relieving herself in front of our fridge and we have both showed her the mess and told her no she goes outside not in the house now I’m more home with her due to my fiancés job but we are trying to figure out how to correct all this (rescue said she was house trained) anyways trying to figure this out and correct because the last thing would be to take her back and I don’t say that lightly and there are no trainers that I’m aware of where I live

Comment: Because doing so gets your attention on the dog rather than the human?